# Help with wiring an electric oven after moving it to be underneath an existing electric hob (UK)

Tags: electrical, wiring, oven

Photos can be seen at: https://i.stack.imgur.com/49w3j.jpg

I currently have an electric oven (Photo 1) on one side of the kitchen, and an electric induction hob (Photo 3) on the other side of the kitchen. There is no gas at the property.

I'm hoping to move the oven from its current location to a new location directly under the hob.
I need some advice on how I can most easily and safely electrically connect the oven once it has been moved.

Some further info which may be of use:

The cable leading from the oven (Photo 5) is mostly concealed in a cavity wall (Photo 6). I can't see where the cable goes to / from and it is tight and cannot be pulled through. Getting to it would be a huge job since it would involve removing most of the kitchen, which I don't want to do.

The hob is wired as shown in Photos 7 and 8 (having removed the plastic plate shown in Photo 9) and can be turned off at a wall mounted cooker switch (Photo 10). This cooker switch turns off only the hob, it does not turn off the oven (the oven does not have a similar switch).
The oven and the hob are on the same circuit - there is a dedicated 32A circuit breaker on the consumer unit in the hallway which turns off both the oven and the hob.

I'm currently wondering whether I can cut the cable leading from the back of oven and terminate that live cable somehow (in case anyone ever wants to put an oven there again in the future). If so, what would be the best way to terminate this live cable?

And then, when in it's new location, can I connect the oven to the existing wiring used by the hob, shown in Photos 7 and 8? Can I make a spur here, for the oven? And if so, how is this best done and should I use a specific size cable? Ideally, the wall mounted cooker switch (Photo 10) would now turn on/off both the hob and the oven.

Any help, including better approaches, would be gratefully received. Thanks!

Comment: Nicely done - lots of clear pictures definitely helps. Putting them directly in the post instead of hosting externally would help even more. Next time...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the hob location, disconnect the existing single cooker outlet connector. Loosen the terminal screws, withdraw the wires, undo the screws at left and right and pull the connector plate forward.

At the hob location fit a dual outlet connector

https://www.tlc-direct.co.uk/Products/AA45DCOP.html

Available from any good electrical supplier.

over the existing flush back box. Reconnect the hob wires, connect the oven wires, put the cables through the cable clamps.

At the previous oven location, re-use the single connector from the hob to terminate the feed cable, putting the cable through the cable clamp. Fit the connector to a single surface back box screwed to the wall. Label it as being the cooker circuit.